# Delphi won't let me insert rows with missing columns, but with triggers and generators for those fields

Tags: delphi, firebird, tclientdataset, dbx

The problem is simple: I have triggers and generators in my Firebird 2.1.4 database to make a column auto increment on each insert.

The architecture of the system is as follows:

```
TSQLConnection > TSQLDataSet -> TDataSetProvider -> (DataSnap) -> TClientDataSet -> TDataSource
```

However, if I try to Post updates in my TClientDataSet with some missing column, Delphi will complain like this:

```
Field 'XXX' must have a value
```

If I use a SQL insert statement with those fields missing, the row gets inserted and the triggers and generators works as expected.

How do I make Delphi (DBX, DataSnap and such) understand what I'm trying to do (and allow it)?

**EDIT**

Providing more information based on @mj2008's comment: this TClientDataSet is being created at runtime, using the CloneCursor method. After calling the CloneCursor, I set this field's Required property to False. It does not help with this issue. Example:

```
myCds.CloneCursor(otherCds, True);
myCds.FieldByName('XXX').Required := False;
```

This results in the same exception being thrown.

Comment: They are probably required fields, so Delphi insists on them having a value. Stop them being required, and it will go away.

Comment: @mj2008 That doesn't help. I edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to set the TSQLDataset's Required property to False too. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement: when you do a TClientDataset setting, the updates are in the end sent to the data access component, in this case TSQLDataset, so even if the TClientdataset doesn't require the field's value, if the data access component requires it the error is raised.

It'll be the same even if data come from a TADODataset, TIbDataset, or whatever.